# Response from server is not showing in Select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, html, asp.net-mvc-4

This my ajax for showing search item in `select2` dropdown. But there is the problem. I am getting server response, but that response is not showing in `select2` dropdown.

```
$('#txtTest').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: "/student/list/",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "Get",
        data: function(query) {
            alert(query.term);
            return { q: query.term };
        },
        processResults: function(data,page) {
            console.log(data);               
            return {
                results:data                    
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult list(string q)
{
    var obj = (from c in db.selects 
               where c.name.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower().Trim())         
               select new
               {
                   Id=c.ID,
                   Text=c.name
               }).ToList();
    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In view my hidden text field

```
<input type="hidden"  id="txtTest" class="input-xlarge" data-placeholder="Choose An Option.." />
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Select2 v4. If that is the case, you need to change your hidden input element to a select element.

From the [Select2 4.0.0 beta 1 release notes](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases):

> `<select>` has replaced `<input type="hidden" />` for **all options**
>   (including remote data)

You could use:

```
<select id="txtTest" class="input-xlarge" data-placeholder="Choose An Option..">
</select>
```

Also, the objects you return should have `id` and `text` properties, whereas they currently have `Id` and `Text` properties. Either change the server code to return the correct property names, or change your `processResults` function to correct the objects.

```
processResults: function(data) {
    return {
        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
            return { id: item.Id, text: item.Text };
        })
    };
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovahxznr/1/)

Comment: I have changed my txt field from <input type="hidden" /> to <select> its not working...

Comment: @ShahzadAshraf - Can you confirm that you are using Select2 v4 (because it differs quite a bit from the previous versions)? Also, can you show what the data returned from the ajax call looks like?

Comment: this my server response..when i type "sh" in input field.[{"Id":1,"Text":"shahzad ashraf"},{"Id":6,"Text":"shah"}]

Comment: Thanks u very much...Bro..its working..can u explain a lit bit about the code u added in processresults...

Comment: @ShahzadAshraf - If the answer solves your problem, you can click the check mark next to it.

Comment: @ShahzadAshraf - The call to [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) creates a new array of objects where the objects have `id` and `text` properties, instead of `Id` and `Text` properties.

Comment: @JohnS - you saved my life man!! This fixes my issue as well - here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049399/select2-dropdown-is-not-showing-while-api-is-working . I will post a proper response on it once I get it cleaned up. Thanks a bunch!